# p-table column wise filter with reactive forms array not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement custom search on primeng p-table columns . p-table is binded with reactive forms array. As everyone can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-ygscqm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) , data gets filtered based on search but when I clear the search I dont see the original data or when I reverse the search characters one by one data does not filter properly.

I am not sure if this is the right way to proceed or using pipe is the solution ?

Comment: I would recommend checking out [mcve] first

Comment: I did not find much examples in combination of p-table with reactive forms array and custome serach witout using '|async'. if we can fix it the way I followed that would be great. I think it is achievable but something is wrong in the way I am filtering it should not be assigned to original array...